# How do I prevent scrolling from pausing after an animation in GSAP when changing the z index

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, gsap

I am using GSAP, Tailwind and SvelteKit for a project and I want to have a video section. The video section should initially display a static image of a video thumbnail and when clicked, it scrolls down to centre the video on the screen, fades the background to black and replaces the thumbnail with a Youtube video embed. Subsequently, on trying to scroll up or down, the video section will revert back to its original state with the static image as the thumbnail.

I found a similar effect to the one I wanted to create on this website: https://nizo.co/

However, when I implementing this, I ran into a problem where the youtube video was not able to be clicked because it was behind the thumbnail. To fix this, I increased the z index of the Youtube embed iframe which solved the issue. However, when trying to scroll up or down out of the video section, the scroll would stop after playing the GSAP animation to fade back in the static thumbnail.

I have tried changing the styles and HTML structure of the website but nothing seems to solve the problem: either the Youtube embed is not interactive or the scrolling stops after the GSAP animation.

Here is a barebones version of the video component:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { ScrollToPlugin } from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin?client";
  import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger?client";
  import { gsap } from "gsap?client";

  import { browser } from "$app/environment";
  import trailerThumbnail from "$lib/images/thumbnails/trailer_thumbnail.png";

  if (browser) {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollToPlugin);
  }

  let showVideoPreview = true;

  const stopVideo = () => {
    showVideoPreview = true;

    const stopVideoTimeline = gsap.timeline();

    stopVideoTimeline
      .to(
        ["#videoSection", "#otherSection"],
        { backgroundColor: "#18181b", ease: "sine.out", duration: 1 },
        0
      )
      .to("#videoTitle", { opacity: 1, display: "inline", duration: 0.4, ease: "sine.out" }, 0);
  };

  const onClickVideo = (e: Event) => {
    const elementRect = (e.target as HTMLButtonElement).getBoundingClientRect();

    const scrollTop = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const centerY = elementRect.top + scrollTop - (window.innerHeight - elementRect.height) / 2;

    const videoTimeline = gsap.timeline();

    videoTimeline
      .to(window, {
        scrollTo: { y: centerY, autoKill: false },
        onComplete: () => {
          gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: "#videoSection",
              start: "top top+=40px",
              end: "top+=80px top+=40px",
              onLeaveBack: stopVideo,
              onLeave: stopVideo
            }
          });
          showVideoPreview = false;
        },
        duration: 0.6
      })
      .to(
        ["#videoSection", "#otherSection"],
        { backgroundColor: "#000", duration: 0.4, ease: "sine.out", delay: 0.3 },
        0
      )
      .to(
        "#videoTitle",
        { opacity: 0, display: "hidden", duration: 0.4, ease: "sine.out", delay: 0.3 },
        0
      );
  };
</script>

<section class="h-screen w-screen" id="otherSection" />

<section class="h-screen w-screen relative flex flex-col" id="videoSection">
  <h2
    class="-top-3 absolute w-full text-center text-4xl sm:text-5xl text-white tracking-tighter font-semibold"
    id="videoTitle"
  >
    Video Title
  </h2>
  <div class="w-full sm:w-5/6 h-4/5 m-auto relative">
    <button
      class="transition-opacity duration-500 {!showVideoPreview &&
        'opacity-0'} absolute inset-0 z-30"
      on:click={onClickVideo}
    >
      <img
        src={trailerThumbnail}
        alt="Trailer video thumbnail"
        class="w-full h-full object-cover object-center sm:rounded-2xl sm:shadow-md"
      />
    </button>
    <div class="transition-opacity duration-500 {showVideoPreview && 'opacity-0'} absolute inset-0">
      <div class="relative h-full w-full">
        {#if !showVideoPreview}
          <iframe
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/example?rel=0&autoplay=1"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            class="w-full h-full sm:rounded-2xl sm:shadow-md absolute inset-0 z-50"
          />
        {/if}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```